# Is there a way to print to the console from a class that does not contain main in Java?

Tags: java

Say we have the class

```
package myTest;

public class a {            
    public static void main(String[] args) {            
        b printToConsole = new b();    
    }    
}
```

which I cannot modify. I also have the class

```
package myTest;

public class b {            
    public static void printThis() {            
        System.out.println("this is a test");           
    }    
}
```

which I can modify. I want to call a (which I cannot modify) and somehow print to the console "this is a test". With the current classes, this obviously does not work and I understand why.

Summary:

Is there a way, without modifying a, to call a and have "this is test" to the console? (b can be modified).

Comment: Put a print statement in `b`'s constructor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could either call the print statement in the constructor of `b`

```
public b() {
    System.out.println("this is a test");
}
```

or from a static initializer

```
static {
    System.out.println("this is a test");
}
```

(The second will only produce output for the first object created)

Answer (score 2):

Put `System.out.println("this is a test");` in the default/no-arg constructor of `b`:

```
public class b {

  public b() {
    System.out.println("this is a test");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> With the current classes, this obviously does not work and I understand why.

Because the `printThis` method of class `b` is not called anywhere in class `a`, so it doesn't get executed. Methods don't run automatically somehow, they have to be called. You'd have to call the method from class `a`:

```
b printToConsole = new b();
printToConsole.printThis();
```

Or you would have to put the content of the `printToConsole` method in the constructor of class `b` (class `a` would not have to be modified then). The constructor is called when a new instance of `b` is created (the `new b();` statement in class `a`):

```
public class b {
    // Constructor
    public b() {
        System.out.println("this is a test");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do it in many ways:-

1st way using constructor

```
class B
{
     public B()
     {
          System.out.println("This is a test");
     }
}
```

2nd way using anonymous block

```
class B
{
     {
          System.out.println("This is a test");
     }
}
```

3rd one is by using static block

```
class B
{
     static{
          System.out.println("This is a test");
     }
}
```

Actually there is priorities of execution of these block if these are stated in a single class as follow:-
1.**Static Block**
2.**Init Block(Anonymous Block)**
3.**Constructor**
These all 3 blocks execute at runtime with object initialization.
basically compiler copy the **init block** to the constructor and it is used for share codes between multiple constructors.